# Is finding a matrix out of some set with a given determinant a hard problem?

Tags: matrices, determinant, computational-complexity

Given $n\ge 2\ \ ,\   u,v,k\ $ integers.

Decision problem :

Does a $n\times n$ - matrix with entries from $u$ to $v$ with determinant $k$ exist?

In which complexity class is this problem ? Is it NP-hard?

A similar problem

Given $n\ge 2\ ,\  k\ $ integer

Is there a latin square matrix of size $n \times n$ with determinant $k$?

What about this problem ?

It is clear that the problems are in NP because the determinant of a given
 matrix can be computed in polynomial time. But I have no idea how to check
 how hard it is to find a matrix with the desired properties or proof that
 there is none.